# Align text centrally vertically in button

Tags: html, css

I'd like to align both sets of text in the buttons centrally vertically. How do I do this?

**My Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/fc6317ne/

```css
a.block {
  color: #ffffff;
  background: #F0F0F0;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  height: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<a href="" class="block active">Button</a>

<a href="" class="block active">Button That Has More Words</a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `display:table` property on anchor and then wrap the text inside a span, and display it as `table-cell`, with vertically aligning the span in middle.

*You wont need to adjust line-height or padding for this*. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fc6317ne/3/)

```css
a.block {
  color: #red;
  background: #F0F0F0;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  height: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  display: table;
}
span {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<a href="" class="block active"><span>Button</span></a>

<a href="" class="block active"><span>Button That Has More Words</span></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `line-height: 60px;` to your `a.block` css

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ghorg12110/fc6317ne/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Lmwaykz6/3/)**

CSS:

```
 a.block {
  color: #000;
  background: #F0F0F0;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  height: 60px;
  line-height:60px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  display: block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
span{
    line-height:22px !important;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

HTML:

```
<a href="" class="block active"><span>Button</span></a>

<a href="" class="block active"><span>Button That Has More Words</span></a>
```